# On the condition for rolling without slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

Imagine a wheel rolling on the floor as shown in the picture. Let $P_{0}$ be a point on the circle wheel such that it's the point of contact between floor and wheel.

The book I am going through mentions that, the condition for rolling without slipping is ,
$$v_{\text{CM}}=Rw$$,
Where $R$ is the radius of circle and $w$ is angular velocity.

**My questions:-**

$(1)$- Why is $v_{cm}=Rw$ the condition for rolling without slipping?

$(2)$- Why is it's said that $P_{0}$ is at rest. My argument is since the point is on the edge of wheel, shouldn't it move with the wheel?

Comment: Bitte : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/638765/how-do-you-define-rolling-without-slipping-when-a-rigid-body-is-rotating-with-an

Comment: 2nd question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174479/how-can-the-contact-point-of-rolling-body-have-zero-velocity#:~:text=If%20the%20wheel%20and%20surface,the%20surface%20will%20be%20negative.&text=1-,The%20velocity%20of%20the%20contact%20point%20is%20zero.,point%20of%20the%20rolling%20body.

Comment: Please boil your questions down to what you still don't understand after reading these posts so a good answer can be written for you